# Do we have any testing framework for Dialogflow ES?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automated-tests, dialogflow-es

I'm working on developing chatbot using Google's Dialogflow.

I'm trying to figure out whether we have any standard automated testing framework for Dialogflow that I can use before moving the code to deployment.

Comment: Hi Siena, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in test feature to uncover bugs and prevent regressions. To test your agent, you create test cases using the simulator to define golden test cases, then you execute test cases as needed.

You could follow these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/test-case#create) following the steps mentioned in the document I shared with you.

Edit 1: As you mentioned that you are using ES and it doesn't support Test Cases, I went on and searched for a [tutorial](https://botflo.com/dialogflow-es-automated-conversation-testing/) that you would find really helpful, since it explains how you can create a unit testing framework within Dialogflow ES.

Comment: We are using Dialogflow ES since the support for creating chatbots in Slack/messenger etc is not enabled yet in the CX version

Comment: @Siena I edited my answer, hope the edit / tutorial helps you :)